# Qualifed this vs simple name in anonymous class

Tags: java, generics, scope

In the following code, why does Java think that the simple name `numCows` might not be initialized?  Why does using a qualified-this prevent the error?

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class CowFarm {

    private final int numCows;

    public CowFarm(int numCows) {
        this.numCows = numCows;
    }

    // Fails to compile
    //
    // CowFarm.java:12: error: variable numCows might not have been initialized
    public final Function<Integer, Integer> MULTIPLY_COWS = (k -> numCows * 2);

    // Works fine
    public final Function<Integer, Integer> DIVIDE_COWS = (k -> CowFarm.this.numCows * 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Java Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html):

> For every access of a... blank final field x, x must be **definitely assigned** before the access, or a compile-time error occurs... Such an assignment is defined to occur if and only if either the simple name of the variable (or, for a field, its simple name qualified by this) occurs on the left hand side of an assignment operator.

`final` fields that appear on the left-hand side of the assignment operator (=) in the class declaration are instantiated before `final` fields in the class constructors. `final` fields qualified by the `this` keywork are instantiated after the class constructor. Consider the following example:

```
public class Foo{

    //Instantiated before constructor
    final Bar bar1 = new Bar();

    //Instantiated by constructor    
    final Bar bar2;

    //Instantiated after constructor
    final Bar bar3 = this.bar2;

    //Compile time error
    final Bar bar3 = bar2;

    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar2 = bar;
    }
}
```

In your case, the problem is that `numCows` is not **definitely assigned** when you try to instantiate `MULTIPLY_COWS`. The `this` qualifier ensures that `numCows` is definitely assigned when `MULTIPLY_COWS` is instantiated.

```
// This works fine, as well
public final Function<Integer, Integer> DIVIDE_COWS = (k -> this.numCows * 2);
```